# Celery not running at times in docker

Tags: python, django, docker-compose, celery

I have been going bonkers over this one, the celery service in my docker-compose.yml just does not pick up tasks (sometimes). It works at times though

Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.6
RUN apt-get update

RUN mkdir /web_back
WORKDIR /web_back

COPY web/requirements.txt ./
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt


COPY web/ .
```

docker-compose.yml 
(Taken out a few services for the sake of understanding)

```
version: '3'
services:

  web_serv:
    restart: always
    build: .
    container_name: web_back_01
    env_file:
      - ./envs/web_back_01.env
    volumes:
      - ./web/:/web_back
    depends_on:
      - web_postgres
    expose:
      - 8282
    extra_hosts:
      - "dockerhost:104.10.4.11"
    command: bash -c "./initiate.sh"

  service_A:
    restart: always
    build: ../../web-service-A/A/
    container_name: web_back_service_a_01
    volumes:
      - ../../web-service-A/A.:/web-service-A
    depends_on:
      - web
    ports:
      - '5100:5100'
    command: bash -c "python server.py"

  service_B:
    restart: always
    build: ../../web-service-B/B/
    container_name: web_back_service_b_01
    volumes:
      - ../../web-service-B/B.:/web-service-B
    depends_on:
      - web
    ports:
      - '5200:5200'
    command: bash -c "python server.py"

  web_postgres:
    restart: always
    build: ./postgres
    container_name: web_postgres_01
    #    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - "5433:5432"
    environment:   # will be used by the init script
      LC_ALL: C.UTF-8
      POSTGRES_USER: web
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: web
      POSTGRES_DB: web
    volumes:
      - pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data/


  nginx:
    restart: always
    build: ./nginx/
    container_name: web_nginx_01
    volumes:
      - ./nginx/:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      - ./logs/:/code/logs
      - ./web/static/:/static_cdn/
      - ./web/media/:/media_cdn/
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    links:
      - web_serv
  redis:
    restart: always
    container_name: web_redis_01
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
    links:
      - web_serv
    image: redis
  celery:
    build: .
    volumes:
      - ./web/:/web_back
    container_name: web_celery_01
    command: celery -A web worker -l info
    links:
      - redis
    depends_on:
      - redis
volumes:
  pgdata:
  media:
  static:
```

settings.py

```
CELERY_BROKER_URL = 'redis://redis:6379'
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'redis://redis:6379'
CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ['application/json']
CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = 'json'
```

Notice the `service_A` and `service_B`, those are the two servies that at times do not get fired up.
Any help in understanding the odd behavior would be very helpful! Thanks

Comment: anyone? I'd really appreciate any help.

Answer (score -1):

So, I *think* I ran into a similar problem. I was pulling my hair out because I was updating my worker.py and then not only would the autoload not reflect any changes, but, the when I'd rerun my `docker-compose up` my changes would still not be reflected.

*Sometimes* when I'd run `docker-compose up --build --force-recreate` my changes would be reflected, but not reliably.

I was able to resolve this problem by doing two things:

1. Remove the `__pycache__` in my worker's directory.
2. Run `$ find . -name "*.pyc" -exec rm {} \;` before doing `docker-compose up --build --force-recreate` when caching behavior persists.

I'm not 100% sure what's going on myself, but its clear that Celery + Docker w/o autoload means that Docker has a tendency to use a cached version of the compiled task. I see a bit of chatter regarding ways to setup autoload with Celery + Docker with things like webdog or modd, but, I have yet to set that up for my project.